# copying many files on zsh

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to copy img1.jpg img2.jpg img3.jpg img4.jpg img5.jpg from my current dir to destination folder I found the bracket syntax and I tried

```
cp ./img{1..5}.jpg /Users/seven/dev/Mentoring/React TS/parallax-bg-img/public/img
```

but also

```
cp /Users/seven/Downloads/img{1..5}.jpg /Users/seven/dev/Mentoring/React TS/parallax-bg-img/public/img
```

I have checked the path with pwd and the are both correct also I tried copying one image at a time and I can not see what am I typing wrong

I'm using iterm2 on Mac

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed you have a space between React & TS.

Try the below with double quote or a slash

```
cp /Users/seven/Downloads/img{1..5}.jpg "/Users/seven/dev/Mentoring/React TS/parallax-bg-img/public/img"
```

Or

```
cp /Users/seven/Downloads/img{1..5}.jpg /Users/seven/dev/Mentoring/React\ TS/parallax-bg-img/public/img
```

Works fine with my zsh on iterm2